# How to plot loss components with tf.keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am building a variational autoencoder (more on that [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-variational-autoencoders-vaes-f70510919f73)) in tensorflow-gpu 2.0 using the Keras high-level API. 
This is my architecture so far. For the sake of simplicity, I have omitted some details about the input paremeters (...).

```
inputs = Input(...)
c1 = Conv2D(...)(inputs)
c1 = ReLU()(c1)

c2 = Conv2D(...)(c1)
c2 = ReLU()(c2)

c3 = Conv2D(...)(c2)
c3 = ReLU()(c3)

c4 = Conv2D(...)(c3)
c4 = ReLU()(c4)

z_mean = Conv2D(...)(c4)

z_log_var = Conv2D(...)(c4)

lat_var = Lambda(...)([z_mean, z_log_var])  # Sampling

dec1 = Conv2DTranspose(...)(lat_var)
dec1 = ReLU()(dec1)

dec2 = Conv2DTranspose(...)(dec1)
dec2 = ReLU()(dec2)

dec3 = Conv2DTranspose(...)(dec2)
dec3 = ReLU()(dec3)

dec4 = Conv2DTranspose(...)(dec3)
dec4 = ReLU()(dec4)

outputs = Conv2DTranspose(...)(dec4)
```

My loss is defined as the mean of the reconstruction loss (MSE) between the inputs and outputs and the Kullback-Leibler divergence between `z_mean` and `z_log_var`:

```
    def my_vae_loss(y_pred, y_gt):
        mse_loss = mse(y_pred, y_gt)
        # mse_loss *= original_dim
        kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
        kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
        kl_loss *= -0.5
        vae_loss = K.mean(mse_loss + GLOBAL.beta*kl_loss)
        return vae_loss
```

Currently, I am plotting my loss after having trained the network with `model.fit()` in the following way:

```
model.compile(..., loss = vae_loss, ...)
history = model.fit(...)

 fig1 = plt.figure()
 plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
 plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
```

**The problem is, I would like to plot the MSE-loss and the KL-divergence separately for each epoch**, whereas currently I am plotting the mean of these components and any specific information is lost. The loss for training should stay the same, however.

I guess I should use a Lambda callback and cache the MSE-loss and the KL-div values during training and in the end plot them. One way to do it would be to take the `inputs`, `outputs`, `z_mean`, `z_var` after each epoch and to calculate the two losses and then cache the values. The problem with that approach is that I haven't found an elegant way to get the values of tensors during training in Keras. Normally, if I need a value at an intermediate layer X, I load a smaller version of the model which has X as its last layer and basically do a prediction.

Anyone having an elegant approach for plotting both loss components separately?